# Third party video detection with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, video

I am building an HTML5 video player with a fall back to flash. The problem is that the videos are served  by a variety of third parties.

Some of the third parties are serving the video based on user agent.

e.g the url will look like this

```
http://www.vidserver.com/files/video?key=XXXXXXXXXX
```

If you are on iOS it will serve mp4, which works fine.

But some third parties are only serving flv to desktop. This means I cannot easily fall-back to flash and will have to force the fall-back with javascript.

Is there a way I can test a url with javascript to determine what video will be served?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a XMLHttpRequest to fetch the page and look at what's returned?

See [an example here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).